# Дублируется код при получении значений из CSV С# CSVHELPER

Tags: c#, csv, csv-helper

В методе при чтении CSV дублируется код, не могу понять почему. Как убрать дубли и почему они происходят? Запись в CSV происходит без них, а вот при чтении начинаются дубли:

Вот вывод в консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Метод целиком:

```
public class Program
{

    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Product(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Research();
    }

    public static void Research()
    {

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Saint\\Desktop\\TaskRetail\\file.csv", false, Encoding.UTF8))
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csv.WriteRecords(products);
            }

            var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
            { 
            Delimiter = ",",
            PrepareHeaderForMatch = header => header.Header.ToLower()
            };

            using (var reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Saint\\Desktop\\TaskRetail\\file.csv", Encoding.UTF8))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))

            {
                var records = csv.GetRecords<Product>();

                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{record.Id} {record.Name}");
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А в файле не дублируется?

Comment: Нет, в файл записывается без дублей. У меня подозрения на строку: "PrepareHeaderForMatch = header => header.Header.ToLower()", так как она игнорирует заголовки, но без этой строки вообще невозможно получить значения

Comment: А если удалить всё из файла и оставить только одну строку данных и заголовки?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать [mcve]. Например, загрузка и разбор XML очевидно не относится к проблеме, а данные можно захардкодировать, причём постарайтесь найти самый короткий набор данных, на котором проблема воспроизводится.

Comment: Затем, у вас есть чтение CSV и запись CSV. Посмотрите в файл, найдите, что из них работает неправильно, и оставьте только это в вопросе.

Comment: Спасибо, понял, исправил

Comment: То есть проблема решена? Если да, вы бы написали ответ в назидание потомкам.

Comment: пример запустил, отлично работает (на случайных данных). значит проблема в инициализаторе products. ищите ошибку в нем.